# how to retrieve portrait photo content data from google people (account)?

Tags: html, google-apps-script

I developped the procedure for the electronic signature.

I wish to retrieve the contents of a unknown photo portrait from the google people ( as account google) to control it.

If this is true for an unknown portrait photo, I would like to replace an other photo as logo in the place of unknown portrait photo.

how to do it ?

thank you for your help

Comment: Can you provide an example of _**"contents of a unknown photo portrait from the google people"**_? What have you researched/tried so far? Please see [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for your message.
For example, after having retrieved the url, from google people (account), here is the link concerning the unknown portrait: https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhiqioyVNKfXNF_8GcHYj6xGll8_Ukhu65UeYTG=s128

From there, I am looking for a solution to know if it is an unknown portrait or not?

if this portrait is unknown, I then force to set up another photo as logo in its place.
how to do .?

Comment: I see. How do you retrieve the `url from google people (account)`? Is it via People API using Apps Script? Will you be able to share your sample code that you're working on?

Comment: for Irvin Jay G. see my answer in your question with my little script, below

Comment: for irvin jay, I think to have found thanks of a variable personn . And I tried to retrieve  :  var default_BLN  = person.photos[0].default; It does not work because of "default" !... How to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your last question, yes , it is from google people API using App Script. I will try to share my little script test for you , for my first time !.
here is my script test, see below . I hope you understand what I mean...

```js
function doGet() {

  var Email_user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log('Saisie signature_20220105_CU-RCF_Personnel_V2_2 : function doGet(e) - Email_user : '+Email_user  );


 Email_user = "siprcf34@radiopresence.com";
  var url_photo = getUser2(Email_user)
   Logger.log('function getUser - parm_photo:'+url_photo ); 
   
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('test1');
}

function getUser2(userEmail) {
  Logger.log(' debut function getUser ');
   
  Logger.log('function getUser - userEmail:'+userEmail);
  var user = AdminDirectory.Users.get(userEmail);

      var user_id = user.id;
      var parm_photo = userphoto ( user_id);
      var UserPhoto = parm_photo [0];  
     
    Logger.log('function getUser - parm_photo:'+parm_photo); 
  return parm_photo;
 }    
 
 function get_namefile(url)
{
   Logger.log('fonction get_namefile - url :'+url );
    var namefile = url.split('/s100/')[1];
    
    Logger.log('fonction get_namefile  - namefile :'+namefile );
    return namefile;
}


function userphoto (user_id) {
var accountId =user_id;
Logger.log ('function userphoto  - N°account id  :'+accountId );

  var val_photoUrl = "";
  var val_namefile = "";

try 
{ var person = People.People.get('people/' + accountId, {personFields: 'names,photos,phoneNumbers,addresses,birthdays,sipAddresses,organizations,genders'});
  //** var val_displayName_P = person.names[0].displayName;
   var val_photoUrl = person.photos[0].url.replace("=s100","=s128");
   var val_namefile = get_namefile(val_photoUrl);
  }
  catch (err)
  {
  Logger.log ('function userphoto  - Error : '+err);
  
  }
  
  var parm_photo = [val_photoUrl ];
return parm_photo;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
    <script>
  
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  
             <div    > 
                <img id="the_photouser" style="border-radius: 50%;"  width="160" height="160" align="center">
                  <br> <br> 
            </div>   

    
    <script>
  var photouser ="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a-/AOh14GhiqioyVNKfXNF_8GcHYj6xGll8_Ukhu65UeYTG=s128";
    console.log(' function data_screen2 - visu_photo - ** -  photouser  :'+photouser); 
    document.getElementById("the_photouser").src = photouser ;
    
  // Here I search the solution to retrieve a content of image url , perhapse it exists a default for an unknown portrait photo, for instance.
  // if yes,  here is a little treatment to replace a new iamge by default by an old image . 
//  var default = true;
//  if (default is true)
//  {
//  var photouser ="https://www.radiopresence.com/Logo_presence.png"
// document.getElementById("the_photouser").src = photouser ;
//   
//   }
   </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're already using method `People.People.get` & it's the way to go. However, upon testing your script, the `People.People.get` w/ resource `people/userID` doesn't return `photos` because you're technically retrieving profile data of a private domain email account, that's why it doesn't work. With that, you need to do is to add all [`profile` scopes](https://developers.google.com/people/v1/how-tos/authorizing#profile-scopes) in your Project's manifest `appsscript.json` [like this](https://imgur.com/a/1OiANol). See [Edit manifest](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/concepts/manifests).

Comment: You can also copy and paste all of the scopes [shared temporarily from here](https://shrib.com/#Anaya7bpDWJm)